# How to change the ordering how the categories are shown in the stacked chart and get rid of "a" in the legend in r?

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, legend, stacked-bar-chart

I've been trying for hours to get rid of the "a" in the legend. I saw solutions here for that but the solution was to get rid of the legend altogether. However, I want to keep it. Apart from that, I want the values to start with the mandatory school at the bottom of the each column and have the highest educational attainment at the top. How can I do this? Please do not close my question. I find it disrespectful since I need support in doing this. Thank you!

```
earnings_data <- tibble::tibble(
  Group.1 = factor(rep(c("(25,34]", "(34,44]", "(44,54]", "(54,65]"), 18)),
  Group.2 = rep(rep(1:2, 9), each = 4L),
  Group.3 = rep(1:9, each = 8L),
  x = c(
    5.06818181818182, 5.80811808118081, 5.90760869565217, 6.00348432055749,
    4.35483870967742, 4.66666666666667, 4.72625698324022, 5.08411214953271,
    4.70833333333333, 5.38095238095238, 5.86842105263158, 6.46428571428571, 4,
    4.92857142857143, 5.31578947368421, 5.28571428571429, 5.3, 6.3,
    5.95652173913043, 6.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4.69230769230769,
    5.54545454545455, 5.73333333333333, 5, 7.26666666666667, 7.13636363636364,
    7.54545454545455, 5, 5.9, 6.82608695652174, 5.83333333333333,
    6.08465608465608, 6.83566878980892, 7.28323197219809, 7.28296438883542,
    5.68085106382979, 6.04819277108434, 6.26519337016575, 6.38515901060071,
    5.74358974358974, 6.57692307692308, 7.23478260869565, 7.52631578947368,
    6.04347826086957, 6.43181818181818, 6.74324324324324, 6.20338983050847,
    6.1031746031746, 7.01630434782609, 7.37894736842105, 7.72950819672131,
    5.70114942528736, 6.46938775510204, 6.73913043478261, 7.19230769230769,
    7.23032069970845, 7.96165644171779, 8.35185185185185, 8.23263327948304,
    6.52486187845304, 7.21951219512195, 7.40825688073395, 7.74803149606299,
    7.59722222222222, 8.47927656367747, 8.64701436130007, 8.67477592829706,
    6.93237410071942, 7.87311178247734, 8.11830357142857, 8.28571428571429
  ),
  share = c(
    9.59238368157303, 9.42485144608869, 9.26469454935699, 9.07884380703652,
    8.90483213980824, 8.60539148301954, 8.19283090969065, 8.803490414879,
    8.91131010179019, 8.73168832315526, 9.20323794967356, 9.77569644399565,
    8.17925322471276, 9.08834712747471, 9.21476857137597, 9.15257840139337,
    10.0311384508647, 10.2230297801189, 9.34140315188156, 10.081749555502,
    9.54246209549822, 8.65267385380536, 9.61288638544082, 9.92766161736722,
    9.46333816119313, 11.7916428151637, 11.1917076248986, 11.4107074514545,
    10.2240665308909, 10.8796735178176, 11.8328259356068, 10.1008185060422,
    11.5162316247324, 11.0922612071819, 11.4220360607478, 11.0137534484817,
    11.6162798457357, 11.1529428342749, 10.8605329926627, 11.0563426797082,
    10.8707064005501, 10.6723937264978, 11.3460546311905, 11.3817646297641,
    12.3577847634247, 11.8603528718889, 11.6892187349767, 10.7415968228904,
    11.5512810253294, 11.3853790943181, 11.5721431438945, 11.6890448739816,
    11.6577862053377, 11.9296316331656, 11.6820892994844, 12.4539762239334,
    13.6845939590431, 12.9194049051995, 13.0979149627558, 12.4499020359058,
    13.3421243900356, 13.3128704475982, 12.8420007999215, 13.4162502721425,
    14.379016594924, 13.7593487022761, 13.5608079256008, 13.1185377538782,
    14.1754108045561, 14.5181162309553, 14.0728463708406, 14.3472850616437
  ),
)
```

```
#create age ranges
age_ranges <- cut(df_final$age, breaks=c(25,34,44,54,65))

#group data by age range, gender, and education level, and calculate mean value
earnings_data <- aggregate(df_final$earnings, by=list(age_ranges, df_final$gender, df_final$education), FUN=mean)

#calculate the percentage of each education level for each age range and gender group
earnings_data <- earnings_data %>%
  group_by(Group.1, Group.2) %>%
  mutate(share = x/sum(x)*100)

# Create a test data frame with one row for each education level
test_data <- data.frame(Group.3 = unique(earnings_data$Group.3))

# Fill in the color for each education level
test_data$color <- c("#2c7bb6", "#abd9e9", "#ffffbf", "#fdae61", "#d7191c", "#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF", "#FFFF00")

# Print out the test data frame
print(test_data)

#create plot with facets and text labels for education share

p <- ggplot(earnings_data, aes(x=Group.2, y=x, fill=interaction(Group.3))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack") +
  facet_wrap(~Group.1,nrow=1) +
  labs(title="Mean Earnings by Age Range and Gender", x="Age Range", y="Mean Earnings") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=colors, name="Gender") +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(round(share,1), "%"), color=as.factor(Group.3)), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), size=3.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values=colors, name="Education Level", labels=c("Mandatory School", "Pre-vocational education", "Short apprenticeship commercial shool", "Diploma middle school", "Apprenticeship", "Full-time vocational school", "Teacher diploma", "Higher professional education", "university degree")) +
  guides(fill=FALSE, color=guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 22, size = 5), reverse=FALSE)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
# Add footnote using ggtext
footnote <- "Note: The first column represents males and the second column represents females."
plot <- p + theme(plot.caption = element_markdown())
plot <- p + labs(caption = footnote)
plot
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, can you post the output of `dput(earnings_data)`? The `a` in the legend come from the color aesthetic. Why do you have `geom_text` with a color and then `scale_color_manual`? As far as I understand the code you should keep `scale_fill_manual` only.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks for your comment. I've added the data to my main posting. Sorry for that!

Comment: Rui is right. You can skip or use the colour argument in `geom_bar` but it does not make a lot of sense in geom text. Especially because (from what I have to assume) it changes your text colour to the background colour of your plot. You probably want to replace your `interaction(Group.3)` with the Education level labels in the `data.frame`. Then you can use `scale_manual_fill` to assign the right colours. Also you need contrast for the colour of the `geom_text` otherwise it will be invisible as you have it now. Then remove the `color` legend and just use the `fill` legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way.
Instead of creating a data.frame with the colors, create a named vector of color codes, with names equal to the unique `Group.3` values and a vector of legend text values. Coerce `Group.3` to factor with the same levels as the colors' names reversing the levels from the highest to the lowest. Also reverse the legend text.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

# Create values, order
fill_colors <- c("#2c7bb6", "#abd9e9", "#ffffbf", "#fdae61", "#d7191c", "#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF", "#FFFF00")
fill_levels <- sort(unique(earnings_data$Group.3))
fill_colors <- setNames(fill_colors, fill_levels)
fill_labels <- c("Mandatory School", "Pre-vocational education", "Short apprenticeship commercial shool", "Diploma middle school", "Apprenticeship", "Full-time vocational school", "Teacher diploma", "Higher professional education", "university degree")

footnote <- "Note: The first column represents males and the second column represents females."

earnings_data %>%
  mutate(Group.3 = factor(Group.3, levels = rev(fill_levels))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Group.2, y = x, fill = Group.3)) + 
  geom_col(position="stack") +
  facet_wrap( ~ Group.1, nrow = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Gender", values = fill_colors, labels = rev(fill_labels)) +
  labs(
    title = "Mean Earnings by Age Range and Gender", 
    x = "Age Range", 
    y = "Mean Earnings",
    caption = footnote
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    plot.caption = ggtext::element_markdown()
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>